# Como usar Chart.Js com ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, chartjs

Bem, estou retornando uma lista de e enviando para `View`. E preciso implementar isso através de um gráfico com `Chart.js`.

Tenho a classe **Pais**:

```
[Table("Pais")]
public class Pais
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PaisId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FertilidadePorAno> FertilidadePorAno { get; set; }
}
```

A classe **FertilidadePorAno**:

```
[Table("FertilidadePorAno")]
public class FertilidadePorAno
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FertilidadePorAnoId { get; set; }
    public Guid PaisId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Ano { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
}
```

E uma classe associativa **PaisFertilidadePorAno**:

```
[Table("PaisFertilidadePorAno")]
public class PaisFertilidadePorAno
{
   public Guid PaisFertilidadePorAnoId { get; set; }

    public string  Nome { get; set; }

    public int Ano { get; set; }

    public double Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Meu `controller` que busca os dados no Banco:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Relatorio(Guid id)
 {
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var entries = db.Database.Connection
   .Query<PaisFertilidadePorAno>(@"SELECT p.Nome, f.Ano, f.Valor from Pais As p
                                                    inner join FertilidadePorAno as f
                                                    on f.PaisId = p.PaisId
                                                    where p.PaisId = @id
                                                    order by f.Ano", new {  Ano = (int?)null, Id = id });
        return View(entries);
    }
```

Retornam os dados para a `View` que atualmente está assim:

```
@model IEnumerable<TaxaDeFertilidade.Models.PaisFertilidadePorAno>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Relatorio";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Relatorio</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ano)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Valor)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ano)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Valor)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Porém, preciso criar um gráfico `chart.js` com essas informações vindas do Banco que são o nome do *Pais*, *Ano* e a *Taxa de Fertilidade* referente aquele 
ano. Como eu faço isso na `View`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma simples de utilizar é utilizando o [Chart.Mvc](https://github.com/martinobordin/Chart.Mvc).

Para utilizar este pacote, basta instalar via NuGet com o seguinte comando:

> Install-Package Chart.Mvc

Após isso, faça algo parecido com isso em sua View:

```
@using Chart.Mvc.ComplexChart;
@using Chart.Mvc.Extensions

<script src="~/Scripts/Chart.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

    var nome = new[] { "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho" };
    var valores = new List<double> { 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40 };

    var barChart = new BarChart();
    barChart.ComplexData.Labels.AddRange(nome);

    barChart.ComplexData.Datasets.AddRange(new List<ComplexDataset>
                           {
                              new ComplexDataset
                                  {
                                      Data = valores,
                                      Label = "My First dataset",
                                      FillColor = "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                                      StrokeColor = "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                      PointColor = "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                      PointStrokeColor = "#fff",
                                      PointHighlightFill = "#fff",
                                      PointHighlightStroke = "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                  }
                          });
}

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
@Html.CreateChart("myCanvas", barChart)
```

Basta você alterar as variáveis **nome** e **valores** para os valores que deseja.

O resultado será isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não colocaria código c# na view desta maneira.

Comment: @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba O código C# que tem é para simular os valores que ele já possui no **Model**. O `barChart` ele pode criar no Controller e repassar para a View, mas seria mais complexo explicar o funcionamento com base na pergunta dele. E o `Html.CreateChart` é um `HtmlHelper` o que é muito utilizado em Asp.Net MVC. Mas concordo com você, não é legal misturar os códigos.

Comment: @Randrade, Atendeu minha necessidade.

Answer (score 1):

Eu aconselharia você implementar seu método como JsonResult e pegar os dados vindos do Json e tratar no seu chart.js  na view, conforme esse exemplo do dotnetfiddle.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/h6lJUN

Espero ter ajudado ;)